# How to make a DIV take up the remaining space to an absolute positioned container at the bottom

Tags: html, css, hover, css-position

- I have a container that holds an image, some text and a footer
- The image is situated at the top with the text underneath, followed by a footer that simply contains some additional metadata
- I want to be able to hover over the content (Excluding the footer) and for it to all highlight
- The issue I have is that I cannot make the "text" div span all the way to the bottom where the absolute positioned footer begins.
- The footer will highlight on hover independently. I don't want the content hover to effect the footer and I don't want the footer hover to effect the content hover
- Here's a codepen link to an example which shows that the blue highlight only covers to the bottom of the text, opposed to the entire panel up until the metadata footer http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVNeqr

An assistance or guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
 <div class="item">
     <div class="content"> 
         <div class="image">
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-300-200-4.jpg"/>
         </div>
         <div class="text"> Text here </div>
     </div>
     <div class="footer"> Footer </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi Vitorino, I thought of this. The issue here is, by hovering over the metadata footer, it causes the panel to light up. I should have stated, the footer is independent. It'll have it's own hover. I don't want the content hover to effect the footer, and I don't want the footer hover to effect the content hover :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of `position:absolute` you can use css3 "flex" property to solve this problem. Try to add this to your code.

```
.item {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
.content {
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

Here's [an example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYoKyg)

Comment: Sergey, that's great. Never knew of this. Thanks everyone for taking the time to respond. Massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
I just added some plain CSS stuff and it seems to work fine.

http://codepen.io/KingK/pen/bVNeoo/

```
 .text
   { height: auto; }
```

Comment: Hi Niels - On a fixed height container, that would certainly work. On this occasion, the content in the "text" class can fluctuate.

Comment: I see. So basically the text can 'expand'?

Comment: I just want to ensure, that no matter what the text size, that the entire panel highlights

Comment: How do I checked a forked item? I'm not signed into a profile.

Comment: Does this work for you? Add more text if you want. http://codepen.io/KingK/pen/bVNeoo/

Comment: OH wait that wasn't your pen?